# Construction of a circle that touches given elements

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line, geometric-construction

**Two congruent circles that touch at point *H* are given. Let the line *p* be their common tangent that doesn't pass through the point *H*. Construct a circle that touches both given circles and the line *p*.**

The most intuitive thing was to construct an equilateral triangle *NOL* (such that *L* is on *p*, and *N* and *O* are on the given circles) and find its circumscribed circle. However, the obtained circle intersects  given circles at *N* and *O*, instead of just touching them. What am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Do you have a geometric reason why the circumscribed equilateral triangle must be tangential to those 2 circles? The 3 points of tangency will form an isosceles triangle (by symmetry), but why must it be equilateral? Is there some angle chasing done? $\quad$ More likely it was just wishful thinking, and you realized that it didn't work out.

Comment: HINT: If A is a center of left circle then ANC should be a straight line inclined at  $ 45 ^{\circ}$ to horizontal.

Comment: @Narasimham That statement doesn't make sense to me. $N$ and $O$ are defined as the tangency points, and the line connecting them is parallel to the horizontal. (OP also defined the center of left circle as G in the diagram). Are you referring to another line? (EG $GNP$ is a straight line. Even then, I don't think any of those angles are $45^\circ$.)

Comment: Hint: Prove algebraically that if the radius of the congruent circles is 1, then the desired radius is 1/4. This makes it easy to then do the construction. $\quad$ (To me, this algebraic approach isn't ideal.)

Comment: Sorry type error; that should be ANC, C is center of common tangent. corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using Descartes theorem; If circles with radii $r_1$. $r_2$ and $r_3$ are mutually tangent, then the radius of the circle touching all can be found by this relation:

$(\frac 1{r_1}+\frac1 {r_2}+\frac 1 {r_3}+\frac 1 R)^2=2 (\frac 1{r_1^2}+\frac1 {r_2^2}+\frac 1 {r_3^2}+\frac 1 {R^2})$

where R is the radius of circle to be found. We have:

$r_1=r_2=r$

$r_3=\infty$

which represent the line p. Putting these vales in relation we get:

$LP=R=\frac r4$

Now it  is easy  to construct the circle: Draw  perpendicular HP from H to p. Draw a circle center on P with radius $\frac r 4$, it intersect HP at point C which is the center of the circle with radius R.Draw circle radius R center at C.

Answer (score 2):

Let the radius of the "big" circles be $r$.

It is fairly easy to show that if you pick $P$ such that $|LP|=\frac{1}{4}r$, and draw the small circle with the centre $P$ and radius $\frac{1}{4}r$, it will touch both the big circles and the line.

That is because this ensures that the right-angled triangle $\triangle PHG$ has the ratio of sides making the right angle of $|PH|:|GH|=3:4$. Therefore, it is one of those $3:4:5$ right-angled triangles, and $|GP|=\frac{5}{4}r=r+\frac{1}{4}r$. In other words, the distance of the centres $G$ and $P$ is exactly equal to the sum of the radii of the circles, and so those circles touch. A symmetrical argument applies to the other big circle.

Now the construction should be immediately obvious.